# 301 Redirect, One Rewrite Works And The Other Does Not

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

Sorry for the long title.  I'm currently writing some 301 redirects and using mod rewrite (Apache) to handle them.  Currently only one of the two 301s I have tried is working.  Here is the code:

```
#301 REDIRECTS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Fox-and-Frank-home\.html$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/contact_us.php [R=301]
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ http://www.domain.com/about/ [R=301,L]
```

about.html properly redirects, but Fox-and-Frank-home.html does not.  I have tried this with other names, other URLs, but it is not working.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have gotten this to work on a completely bare .htaccess file.  Do 301 redirects need to be at the very top before everything else?

Comment: both files are located at the webroot, right?

Comment: I don't have either files created.  The goal is if the user is linked that it will redirect properly.  I know little about .htaccess and this kind of stuff in general.  This may not be the best approach I'm taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a L (last) flag on your Fox-and-Frank rewrite, so other rules can potentially be processed, and definetly will be in a `.htaccess` (where you need to use the `END` flag).

Try changing it to:

```
RewriteRule ^Fox-and-Frank-home\.html$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/contact-us.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

Where:

- NC makes it a case insensitive check (so fox-and-frank-home would
  redirect to)
- R=301 is the 301 redirect (although you can just put R
  and 301 would be assumed I always specify it personally)
- L tells
  mod_rewrite to stop processing further rules (but as its in a
  `.htaccess.` you may need to use `END` instead - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).

Regards.

Comment: Thank you.  Very well written :).